# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 72.14.213.109:587

Tags: asp.net, email, gmail, system.net.mail

```
 //Create Mail Message Object with content that you want to send with mail.
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage MyMailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("dotnetguts@gmail.com", "myfriend@yahoo.com",
        "This is the mail subject", "Just wanted to say Hello");

        MyMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;

        //Proper Authentication Details need to be passed when sending email from gmail
        System.Net.NetworkCredential mailAuthentication = new
        System.Net.NetworkCredential("dotnetguts@gmail.com", "myPassword");

        //Smtp Mail server of Gmail is "smpt.gmail.com" and it uses port no. 587
        //For different server like yahoo this details changes and you can
        //get it from respective server.
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient mailClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

        //Enable SSL
        mailClient.EnableSsl = true;

        mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        mailClient.Credentials = mailAuthentication;

        mailClient.Send(MyMailMessage);
```

Thats my code & it throws error : 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 72.14.213.109:587

Code Reference : [here](http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2006/10/send-email-from-gmail-in-aspnet-20.html)

Please tell me how can i sought it out ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check both of the following points

1- Check that this port 587 is open on your machine

2- Check if your antivirus is blocking the connection to your port

Regards.

Comment: how can i check this ? please help

Comment: Check that the firewall behind this machine is set to receive and send data through this port,
also to check the antivirus first disable all antivirus options and then try to send your e-mail and after you send your e-mail successfully try to enable one antivirus option at a time

Comment: This problem was driving me crazy because emails wasn't sent only from the server, but in the development environment everything was ok. Thanks to this response, I have seen the fact that the server anti-virus was different, which was blocking the SMTP sending.

Answer (score 1):

If your have any antivirus software running, check the access protection, unblock "prevent mass mailing worms from send mail"

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually change the username and password?